# <iframe> embed being stripped from rich text field

Tags: wygwam

I have a wygwam rich text area field, and when I switch to the "Source" view, paste in a standard  embed snippet from Vimeo, then switch back to the HTML view, the  snippet is immediately deleted. Before I save the page or do anything else, simply by changing views. If I try saving before switching back to HTML view, the  is also deleted.

How do I prevent wygwam from deleting my vimeo  code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the you have "Restrict allowed HTML" set to YES for your field's WYGWAM configuration. Change **Restrict allowed HTML** to "**NO**" and it should work how you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jules, this solved the problem perfectly! It didn't occur to me this could be a feature, so I was off on the wrong track.